# Should I use ESAPI or not, and is there a replacement?

Tags: spring-security, esapi

I have noticed that ESAPI slows down my application in a big way.  I of course like the idea,  but I have inherited an application that uses it and I keep getting an error.  I am using Spring boot 1.5.7  and keeping up as much as I can with other dependencies to the most modern.  So I am wondering if this is even needed any more?

But after much research,  it looks like ESAPI is a goner.   I personally never understood what it was supposed to do other than OWASP says it was a good thing.  Now I do respect OWASP and would like to secure my application as much as possible.

So my question is,  after removing ESAPI I have found some lines of code that use is like this:

```
 ESAPI.encoder().encodeForJavaScript(ControllerHelper.getJavascriptStuff());
```

What should I use as a replacement? and why?

Comment: What parts of ESAPI is your application using?

Comment: Just the encoder?

Comment: Yes,   Just the encoder

Comment: So the question here isn't really within the SO guidelines, but in short:  ESAPI's not dead, but we definitely can't do more than emergency maintenance with the current crew of 2.  That said, if all you need is encoding, and don't need logging (which needs updating) or the validation framework, use the OWASP Encoder project.  Caveat:  decoding is not provided.

Comment: Still, I have a hard time believing ESAPI causes an actual performance decrease.  Did you run it through a profiler and have identified ESAPI as the bottleneck?  I've personally deployed it in a dozen public-facing high throughput applications and ESAPI encoding was *never* a bottleneck.

Comment: The reason I find it hard to believe is that I spent a big chunk of last fall fixing bugs in the encoder, and at the end of the day it's processing on ints and chars.  It would be difficult to get much faster.

Comment: @avgvsts,   It could easily be something else.  I did not run it  through a profiler and I apologize for making such a general comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is borderline NOT a good question for SO, but at the same time, it's definitely going to come up for just about anyone at this point.  So I'll mark this off as a community wiki, and it can be migrated to a better home later.

So the core question is this:

> So my question is, after removing ESAPI I have found some lines of
>   code that use is like this:
>
> `ESAPI.encoder().encodeForJavaScript(ControllerHelper.getJavascriptStuff());`
>   What should I use as a replacement? and why?

IF *ALL* you need is an encoder, use the lightweight [OWASP Encoder Project.](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder)

However that project won't also give you a decoder.

The *why* part.  The part that deserves a wiki.

In all application development, its the responsibility of the programmer to ensure that data is *always* treated *only* as data.  In the case you present here, the developer was using the encoder to ensure that data passed to the client, was always going to be treated as data by the JavaScript interpreter.

Failure to do this *could* result in a user submitting for example, javascript code as input, and then your application then turning around and serving it to another user.  In the worst case, it could be used to drop a malware file inside the perimeter of the corporate network.

But there could be more to worry about here as well.  Is the javascript payload going to be rendered into HTML?  If so, then maybe it should be HTML-encoded first.  Preventing XSS is a broad topic, you can get started [here.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 0):

StringUtils.escapeJava(str) works and did not shows in vulnerability.